# UpdateResource fails...what i am doing wrong?

Tags: delphi, resources

I am trying to update a bitmap inside an exe. I opened resource hacker and saw that the resource name is 6801 so i came up with this code

```
ResUpdate:=BeginUpdateResource(Pchar(szExplorer),false);
ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
if ResUpdate<>0 then
begin
  FS:=TFileStream.Create(szBitmap,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  SetLength(thebmp,FS.Size);
  dwSize:=FS.Size;
  FS.ReadBuffer(thebmp[0],FS.Size);
  FS.Free;
  UpdateResource(ResUpdate,RT_BITMAP,MAKEINTRESOURCE(6801),LANG_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,@thebmp[0],dwSize);
  EndUpdateResource(ResUpdate,false);
end;
```

The call to UpdateResource fails. Where am i wrong ?

Comment: You really need to verify whether the code works with an ordinary resource inside an ordinary executable, and mention that in the question. If it doesn't, focus on that. If it does, the problem is related to the Explorer hacking you are attempting.

Comment: The code works fine on other executables except explorer what could be the cause ?

Comment: Why would you *possibly* have a need to hack resources in an EXE programmatically? This sounds like some kind of user-hostile software, and I'm not terribly interested in encouraging it.

Comment: @Cody i want to change the start button of windows 7 does that sound hostile ?

Comment: @Cody, its not that unusual to do.  Consider apps that allow a user to create executable/self-running versions of documents or presentations.  They use a core runtime executable, replace a specific resource with the document, and rename the executable.  Not hostile at all.

Comment: @david i want to learn how can i do this is for my personal knowledge...Yes i can do it with resource hacker but how resource hacker does it...Any way i found the answer explorer.exe is locked so you can't use the apis to change a resource you must do it by reading the .rsrc section in the PE locating the offset of the bmp replace it with mine then overwrite the original file...I will stop posting questions here because nobody is giving an useful answer you are "experts" in googling and critics that don't have any kind of sense.

Comment: @david you have a serious problems...initially i thought you have 16 years old but when i saw that you have 40 i got scared.Chill out man and admit that you comments don't have any sense...sorry for the 'retard' part i should said:lack of programming knowledge.

Comment: @opc0de: I'm not sure what David's comments were that you are referring to, since they've been deleted. However, I'm sure he meant no offense, and I certainly didn't either. The point is that there's a *reason* explorer.exe is locked. You're not *supposed* to be modifying its resources while the application is running. That has serious stability implications, and is definitely not a good idea for production software. David's point (as is mine) is that if you're just trying to do this for yourself, Resource Hacker is a better bet. Do **not** try and overwrite explorer.exe while it's running.

Comment: @Cody: I assume the David opc0de is responding to is David Heffernan. In which case, I'm not too surprised. David does have a tendency to be arrogant and argumentative just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Craig: Yes, that's the David I thought he was referring to. We apparently have a lot of similar interests, as we frequently answer many of the same questions. I've never seen him be "arrogant...for the sake of it". Argumentative, perhaps. I'm that way, too, as are most programmers. The point was to express that he surely meant no offense by it. It's hard to stay quiet when you see questions from people clearly trying to do things that you *know* they shouldn't do, often from bad experiences trying to do the same things yourself! Easy to get classified as "argumentative" when the OP disagrees.

Comment: @opc0de: Explorer is part of Windows, and therefore there's a strong possibility that MS will have it as a specially protected file. At a minimum, your change will be overwritten next service pack. So, 2 options: 1) If you're specifically wanting to modify the Start Button, then I suggest an entirely different approach. MS does provide some "white-labelling" techniques, and perhaps they've published a more specific way of changing the button. 2) If you want to learn about resource replacement - rather do so using one of your own EXEs. You'll have more control that way.

Comment: @Cody: I agree that David wouldn't have _intended_ to offend, but the thing about offending people is that it's seldom intentional. Furthermore, David is a very helpful member of this community, he certainly seems to have more free time than I do. And I hear you on the steering people away from dangerous waters. E.g. I generally answer threading questions with some form of "Don't do it!"

Comment: @opc0de: Another thing. This is the second question of yours I've read. And in both, the people _trying to help_ you have had to dig for more details about your problem. I suggest you rather make every effort to provide as much relevant info as possible, rather a little too much than too little. ;) And if someone doesn't know something you didn't mention, or asks for more information, be as polite as possible - remember, these people are _trying to help_ ***you*** .

Comment: If i receive a good answer i am not a hypocrite to don't apreciate help.But when i hear mumbleing about that's a windows file , you are trying to make some malware , that is girl talk and i can't stand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you say the call to `UpdateResource` fails. The only result you're checking is that of `BeginUpdateResource`, which is apparently failing with error code 50, `Error_Not_Supported`.

Based on the resource number and the variable name that holds the file you want to update, I think you're trying to modify the "Start orb" bitmap of Windows Explorer. The API documentation tells you that you need to be able to get write access to the file you wish to update, and in particular that the file you want to update **cannot currently be running**. Make sure you shut down Explorer before you try to modify it.

Comment: i termimated explorer. did u ran the code? the call to updateresource fails ! i run my code in olly so i don't need to check evrey api kill explorer then run the code and you will see that updateresource fails with: The request is not supported...